# What does "much less than" mean while comparing measures?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a compact topological group, and there are two complex measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. From my textbook, it appears "$\mu_1\ll\mu_2$"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures

Comment: It is the symbol for absolute continuity.

Comment: "much less than" is context dependant. If you're consider heights of a person then fractions of millimeter are much less than. If you're considering atomic interactions fractions of millimeter is much greater than. You typically only see it on the context of applications where you're considering approximations.